# User defined function with CASE statement inside

Tags: sql-server

How can use case statement inside a T-SQL scalar function for the following code?
(since dynamic SQL is NOT Allowed on T-SQL scalar functions)

I want to switch / case on @Table

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRowVersion] (@Id INT, @Table VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS BINARY(8) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @rowVersion AS BINARY(8)
IF @Table = 'Department' AND @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion =  MAX([RowVersion]) FROM Department
IF @Table = 'Department' AND @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion =  [RowVersion] FROM Department WHERE Id = @Id
RETURN @rowVersion
END
GO
```

in example..

begin case..

case @Table = "Region".....

```
IF @Table = 'Department' AND @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion =  MAX([RowVersion]) FROM Department
IF @Table = 'Department' AND @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion =  [RowVersion] FROM Department WHERE Id = @Id
RETURN @rowVersion
```

case @Table = "Deparment"....

```
IF @Table = 'Department' AND @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion =  MAX([RowVersion]) FROM Department
IF @Table = 'Department' AND @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion =  [RowVersion] FROM Department WHERE Id = @Id
RETURN @rowVersion
```

...
...
... and so on ..
case default....

```
RETURN @rowVersion
```

end case..

I can't go beyond this point

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRowVersion] (@Id INT, @Table VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS BINARY(8) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @rowVersion AS BINARY(8)
   IF @Table = 'Department'
      BEGIN
         IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM [Department]
         IF @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM [Department] WHERE Id = @Id
      END
   ELSE IF @Table = 'Address'
      BEGIN
         IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM [Address]
         IF @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM [Address] WHERE Id = @Id
      END
   ELSE IF @Table = 'AddressType'
      BEGIN
         IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM [AddressType]
         IF @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM [AddressType] WHERE Id = @Id
      END
   ELSE IF @Table = 'ContactType'
      BEGIN
         IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM [ContactType]
         IF @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM [ContactType] WHERE Id = @Id
      END
   RETURN @rowVersion
END
GO
```

I got error:

Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 5
Cannot drop the function 'dbo.GetRowVersion', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetRowVersion, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 13]
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Comment: 1)Is RowVersion column is same in both the Table i.e Region and Department.2)Both the case structure is similar what Exactly you try to achieve.3 )I think if Case @Table is changed then the select Table should be changed too.

Comment: yes is the same column for the tables.

Comment: I am trying to execute the same query but on different table i.e.

Comment: Looking on the errormessage I'd guess Id is a uniqueidentifier in one of the tables, are you sure Id is of type int in all tables?

Comment: your a brave!! the address table is a GUID key..

Comment: Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

It seem that the solution could be like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRowVersion] (@Key NVARCHAR(36), @Table NVARCHAR(20)) RETURNS BINARY(8) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Id INT, @rowVersion AS BINARY(8)
      SELECT @Id = CONVERT(INT, @Key)
   IF @Table = 'Department'
      BEGIN
         IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM [Department]
         IF @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM [Department] WHERE Id = @Id
      END
   ELSE IF @Table = 'Address'
      BEGIN
         IF LEN(@Key) = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM [Address]
         IF LEN(@Key) > 0 SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM [Address] WHERE Id = @Key
      END
   ELSE IF @Table = 'AddressType'
      BEGIN
         IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM [AddressType]
         IF @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM [AddressType] WHERE Id = @Id
      END
   ELSE IF @Table = 'ContactType'
      BEGIN
         IF @Id = 0 SELECT @rowVersion = MAX([RowVersion]) FROM [ContactType]
         IF @Id > 0 SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM [ContactType] WHERE Id = @Id
      END
   RETURN @rowVersion
END
GO
```